# Jquery stopped working after adding script which loads additional content

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, checkbox

I have a problem with **jquery**. I have added t my website a script which loads additional content to the page.

The problem is that on the same page I have also a javascript which binds checkboxes - it stopped working because of `read()` function. The previous solution I received here didnt work (or I couldnt make it work) so I decided to make a short example (the binding script is at the end):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Ajax Rotating Includes Script</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var loadedobjects = ""
      var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname

        function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
          var page_request = false
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
            page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
          else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
            try {
              page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {
              try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
              } catch (e) {}
            }
          } else return false
          page_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            loadpage(page_request, containerid)
          }
          page_request.open('GET', url, true)
          page_request.send(null)
        }

        function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
          if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText
        }

        function loadobjs() {
          if (!document.getElementById) return
          for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var file = arguments[i]
            var fileref = ""
            if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) { //Check to see if this object has not already been         added to page before proceeding
              if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) { //If object is a js file
                fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
              } else if (file.indexOf(".css") != -1) { //If object is a css file
                fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
              }
            }
            if (fileref != "") {
              document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
              loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>    
    <div id="leftcolumn">
      <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external.htm', 'rightcolumn');">Porsche Page</a>
      <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external2.htm', 'rightcolumn');">Ferrari Page</a>
      <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external3.htm', 'rightcolumn');">Aston Martin Page</a>

      <div style="margin-top: 2em">Load CSS & JS files</div>
      <a href="javascript:loadobjs('ajaxfiles/style.css', 'ajaxfiles/tooltip.js');">Load "style.css" and "tooltip.js"</a>    
    </div>    
    <div id="rightcolumn" class="qqryq"><h3>Choose a page to load.</h3></div>
    <div style="clear: left; margin-bottom: 1em"></div>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="master" value="1">Wódz<BR>
      <div class="test">
        --<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="slave" value="1"><BR>
        --<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="slave" value="1"><BR>
        --<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="slave" value="1"><BR>
        --<input type="checkbox" name="qqryq" class="slave" value="1"><BR>
      </div>
    </form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".slave").click(function () {
        if (this.checked == true) {
          $(".master").attr('checked', this.checked);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

At the end there is script that I was using before adding ajax content loading. Then I was told to modify it like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".test").on('change', '.slave', function () {
      if (this.checked) $(".master").attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
  });
</script>
```

What should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a stray `* /` at the end of your first big `<script>` block, and it's causing a syntax error. Removing that should solve your issue.

The end of that block (around line 57 or so) is currently:

```
        if (fileref != "") {
          document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
          loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
      }
    } * /
</script>
```

And it should be:

```
        if (fileref != "") {
          document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
          loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just as a quick comment: since you are using jQuery now, you might be interested in using it for some of the other parts of the page. For instance, jQuery has method [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that does work similar to your `ajaxpage` function.

Comment: Thanks, but this was an error in coping code here. I am not very skilled in jquery, so it will be hard for me to change this function.

Comment: It did not slove my problem I would appreciete any other suggestions

Comment: Would you mind fixing the copy/paste error and updating the question? In my test environment, your code worked for me once `* /` was removed.

Comment: For me it worked too. Lol I dont know how it happened because I was trying to make it working for few hours... Anyway, thanks for help